# Shaping map inside QGIS layout?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, print-composer, layouts

I'm composing a print layout with a map on QGIS, and I'm trying to shape the map based on a layer.

I have a layer that sets the limit of the study area, and I need to put on the layout only the things inside the limit. Outside the limit of the study area I want it to be empty, without the satellite image and other informations.

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: In ArcGIS Desktop a data frame can be graphically clipped to a feature or features in a layer via its properties. Perhaps look for similar terminology.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your shapefile to mask the area outside the study area using `Inverted polygon` from `Layer Properties -> style` as in the images below:

Single style:

[image]

Select `Inverted Polygons`:

[image]

The result will hide the region outside the study area:

[image]